# Regex allow zero and one decimal point at the beginning or between numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm setting up a input validation for rate per annum that will limit up to 100 and include 0 and one decimal point. The problem is it doesn't allow 0 and decimal point.

```
if(!/^0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100)$/.test(input.value)){
      input.value = '';
}
```

I would like it to accept 0 and only one decimal point at beginning or between numbers any idea on how to fix this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Decimal point? Do you mean `0.1`?

Comment: `/^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?|100(?:\.0+)?)$/`

Comment: Yes 0.1, 0.13, 0.999